# Oracle SQL load table columns having special characters

Tags: sql, string, oracle, character, cjk

I am loading and inserting data into an Oracle database. When I encounter special characters that look like Chinese characters, I am getting an error like row rejected because maximum size of column was exceeded. I am not getting this error for rows which have English characters which appear to be of same length for same column. I am using SUBSTR and TRIM function but it is not working. How can I determine whether the length of a string which is in Chinese exceeds column size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your columns are defined as `VARCHAR2(XX)`  [for example `VARCHAR2(20)`], you will receive an error if you try to insert a string that is more than XX **bytes** long.

The function `SUBSTR` calculates length in number of **characters**, not **bytes**. To select a substring in bytes, use the function [`SUBSTRB`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm#i87066).

```
SQL> select substr('ЙЖ', 1, 2) from dual;

SUBSTR('ЙЖ',1,2)
------------------
ЙЖ

SQL> select substrb('ЙЖ', 1, 2) from dual;

SUBSTRB('ЙЖ',1,2)
-------------------
Й
```

**Edit:** As suggested by [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6703/adam-hawkes), you can use character arithmetics if you define your columns and variables as `VARCHAR2 (XX CHAR)`. In that case your columns will be able to store XX characters, in all character sets (up to a maximum of 4000 bytes if you store it in a table).

Comment: You might want to suggest changing the schema definitions from `VARCHAR2(XX)` to `VARCHAR2(XX CHAR)` to have the column lengths be in characters instead of bytes.

Comment: after i changed the column schema definition using VARCHAR2(XX CHAR), the problem of row rejecttion got eliminated, but i have to load this value from staging to a main table where i can not change the schema definition, so , i did a substr which will restrict it to not to be  more than column size, but now i am getting a new error while doing a SELECT * FROM TABLE, ORA-29275: partial multibyte character.